# PyTorch Total CUDA time

Tags: pytorch, autograd

Autograd profiler is a handy tool to measure the execution time in PyTorch as it is shown in what follows:

```
import torch
import torchvision.models as models

model = models.densenet121(pretrained=True)
x = torch.randn((1, 3, 224, 224), requires_grad=True)

with torch.autograd.profiler.profile(use_cuda=True) as prof:
    model(x)
print(prof)
```

The output looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------
Name                                        CPU time        CUDA time            Calls        CPU total       CUDA total
-----------------------------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------
conv2d                                    9976.544us       9972.736us                1       9976.544us       9972.736us
convolution                               9958.778us       9958.400us                1       9958.778us       9958.400us
_convolution                              9946.712us       9947.136us                1       9946.712us       9947.136us
contiguous                                   6.692us          6.976us                1          6.692us          6.976us
empty                                       11.927us         12.032us                1         11.927us         12.032us
```

Which will include many lines. My questions are:

1) How can I use autograd profiler to get the entire CUDA time? (i.e., sum of CUDA time column)

2) Is there any solution to use it pragmatically? For example, `prof[0].CUDA_Time`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[item.cuda_time for item in prof.function_events]
```

will give you a list of CUDA times. Modify it depending on your needs. To get the sum of CUDA times for example:

```
sum([item.cuda_time for item in prof.function_events])
```

Be careful though, the times in the list are in microseconds, while they are displayed in milliseconds in `print(prof)`.

Comment: If someone wants to get the same in current version of PyTorch profiler (actually torch.autograd module [is considered legacy and will be deprecated](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/profiler.html)):
`[item.cuda_time for item in prof.key_averages()]`